# Wordpress Plugin to group subscribers

Tags: wordpress, subscriber

Do you know a Wordpress plugin that provides the ability to group subscribers? It would be nice if there was a page for each group where a photo and some information can be inserted.

The final website will be for a basketball club. So I need the groups as the teams.

I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there isn't such a plugin. Instead I used [Joomla!](http://joomla.org) with the extension [Club](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/membership/8612) by Daniel Scott.
This is perferct for sport club sites.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a plugin that does just what you're looking for: [User Groups](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-groups/)

Answer (score 1):

A plug-in like [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) allows you to attach custom meta fields to users.  You could set up a text field called "Team" for your users, then you can run a custom query against that field to present a list of members of each team on a custom page.

There's also a plug-in called [User Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/) that allows you to set up explicit groups of members.

I haven't used either plug-in, so while I can't personally vouch for their usability, they do come highly recommended from some of my colleagues.

---

#### Update

There's also a plug-in I wrote some time ago called [RegLevel](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reglevel/).  It was used at the time create separate user groups for Affiliate sales by a specific client, though I've spoken with people who have used it in other ways as well.  If you pair it with a role management plug-in (like [Role Scoper](http://agapetry.net/news/introducing-role-scoper/)), you can create custom "Roles" with custom titles.

So a specific use case:

1. Copy the "Subscriber" role and create a "Team 1" role a "Team 2" role and a "Team 3" role
2. Use RegLevel to create custom registration URLs for each team

Anyone who uses, say, http://blog.url/?reglevel=team1 to create an account will automatically be assinged to the *Team 1* role.  If anyone signs up as a regular user, you can easily move them from the *Subscriber* role to the *Team 1* role.

Comment: I already found those two plugins aswell. For the first method I am too lazy because I am doing this for free. :P

Comment: I'd be very careful equating laziness with "doing this for free."  WordPress itself is free, built by developers who are mostly working for free, and you're on a free forum asking for help ... :)  But if you don't want to try the Cimy plug-in, give User Access Manager a try.  Also, see the other option I've posted ...

Comment: The User Access Manager is not what I am looking for because it doesn't have any kind of group pages and the group pages should the centre of all this. But I will have a look at your RegLevel plugin. Thx for your FREE advice ;)

Comment: The only way you can get "group pages" would be to convert your system to a BuddyPress installation and use their built-in social networking features ... which might be overkill for what you're doing.  The alternative would be custom coding in a custom page template that pulls a list of users associated with a group.